# Error when generating the WSDL / rule project

Tags: deployment, wsdl, rules, business-rules, ilog

I am working on a rule project with WODM 7.5.

I deploy my ruleApp project from rule designer to rule execution server, and when i want to download/print the WSDL I get this error :

```
 ilog.rules.res.decisionservice.xu.IlrWsdlGenerationException: Impossible de générer le WSDL à partir de l'ensemble de règles /RuleApplication1/1.0/LoyaltyCategoryArules/1.0., error code: GBRXH0001E
```

Anyone knows where the problem is ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your project successfully build in. It could be about some errors in your rule flow.